# Parse from javascript var with SimpleHTMLDom

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl, simple-html-dom

I have this code that outputs me source page of source URL with curl!

```
$url = 'http://source-page.com';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // add this one, it seems to spawn redirect 301 header
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'); // spoof
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = str_get_html($output);
```

In $output i have this:

```
var flashvars = {

    "image_url":"http://path-to-image.com",
    "video_title":"This is video title",
    "videoUrl":"http://this-is-path-to-mp4.com"

}
```

I want to echo videoUrl and I have tried with this:

```
$videoUrl = $html->find('flashvars[0].videoUrl');
echo $videoUrl
```

And is giving me empty results. What is a good code for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else suggessted regex + json_decode and then deleted it.
Here's what I would do:

```
$output = <<<EOF
var flashvars = {

  "image_url":"http://path-to-image.com",
  "video_title":"This is video title",
  "videoUrl":"http://this-is-path-to-mp4.com"

}
EOF;

$str = preg_match('/var flashvars = (\{.*?\})/s', $output, $m);
$data = json_decode($m[1], true);
echo $data['videoUrl'];
```